# Rails redirect_to not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've tried looking at other answers for this but I can't seem to figure out why my redirect isn't working.

So I'm using Devise with Rails 3.1, and I'm making a shopping site. Visitors aren't allowed to add things to their cart unless they are signed in. This is what I'm having trouble with: if they aren't signed in, I want to redirect them to the Items index page. Here's what I have:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def add_to_cart
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if current_user
      @item.update_attributes(:cart_id => @current_cart.id)
      redirect_to :back
    else
      redirect_to categories_path, notice: 'You must sign in to add an item to your cart.'
    end
  end
.
.
.
end
```

As of right now, when I click the link to add to cart, the method gets executed (I can see Rails loading and defining @item in the server log), and it reaches the 'else' statement, but no redirect happens.

I've already generated scaffolding for the index, new, etc. (all the RESTful actions). Also, I'm sure that I'm reaching the add_to_cart method because I've tried debugging with some puts statements. What's happening here?

**EDIT:**

Also, another weird thing which may be of use... The server seems to try to execute this method twice, and tries to 'get' categories twice:

`Started GET "/items/3/add_to_cart" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-12 16:53:11 -0800
  Processing by ItemsController#add_to_cart as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 
  Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/categories
Completed 302 Found in 26ms`

`Started GET "/items/3/add_to_cart" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-12 16:53:11 -0800
  Processing by ItemsController#add_to_cart as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 
  Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/categories
Completed 302 Found in 25ms`

`Started GET "/categories" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-12 16:53:12 -0800
  Processing by CategoriesController#index as JS
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 
Rendered categories/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 28.5ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)`

`Started GET "/categories" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-12 16:53:12 -0800
  Processing by CategoriesController#index as JS
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 
Rendered categories/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 30.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)`

**EDIT 2 (as requested by Delba)**

```
resources :items do
  member do
    get 'add_to_cart'
  end
end
```

**EDIT 3: changing the else statement to respond to javascript**

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { redirect_to items_path, notice: 'You must sign in to add an item to your cart.' }
  end
```

Comment: Are you using an ajax form? (`remote: true`)

Comment: @Delba Yes. Here's my link to add to cart: %= link_to 'Add to Cart', {:controller => "items", :action => "add_to_cart", :id => item.id },
       :remote => true %>

Comment: You shouldn't use GET for `add_to_cart`. Use POST. Post your routes please.

Comment: Ok, then you should respond to this call with javascript.

Comment: 1. Your route is wrong. It should be a POST(because you are creating smthg) not a GET. 2. An item may belong to multiple carts, so it will be a `many-to-many` relationship (thus there can't be a `cart_id` on `items` table). 3. It should `create` a reference, not `update`. 4. When you make a javascript form, respond with javascript!

Comment: @Delba Can you explain how I might do the javascript stuff? I've tried using a respond_to do |format| block but I can't seem to get it to work. Also I want each item to have a cart_id because each item is unique (used goods), which is why I have a cart_id field.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. respond with `format.js` and write you js in app/views/items/add_to_cart.js.erb

Comment: @Delba No problem. One last thing if you wouldn't mind... Can you tell me how I can change my respond_to block to redirect to the items index with the proper notice? I put what I have in EDIT 3

Comment: If it's ajax, you don't need to redirect because you won't left the page. When you write your remote form, you are only asking the server to send you some js. You will stay on the same page

Comment: @Delba Ok thanks. And as for the double requests... any idea why that may be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who may need answers to this question, simply replace redirect_to statements with the following:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
```

Then, in your views under items, make a add_to_cart.js.erb page, consisting of javascript to make notices, or do whatever. Here's what I put in mine:

```
alert("Need to be signed in")
```

EDIT: Also, for the part where it executes twice: this is somewhat unrelated, but for some reason by default Rails includes duplicate Javascripts. Specifically, look at application.js: it says require jquery and require jquery_ujs. Disable one of these and you're home free.

To disable one of these javascripts:

Go to assets/application.js

Remove the comments (the // ) before require jquery, require tree .

This way, Rails doesn't assume the default and instead includes only jquery and whatever other javascripts you have in assets/javascripts